# Java Generics : Cannot convert from Object to T

Tags: java, generics, casting, java-8

I have many response objects that I need to give to ui. I want to have a template so that I can do it, so far below code has not worked.

```
private <T> T getResult(Class clazz){
    String fileName = "/path/file.json";
    File file = new File(BaseEndpoint.class.getResource(fileName.getFile());
    T result = null;

    try {
        result = mapper.readValue(file, clazz);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: please share your json file as well.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Why? It is probably not of interest for this code.

Comment: @Raghuveer Does "has not worked" mean "did not compile"? If so, what was you error? If not, what happened instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T` can be not `Object`. For instance, it might be `BaseEndpoint` because it meets the condition `T extends Object`.

You need to cast the result of `mapper.readValue(file, clazz)` to `T`:

```
result = (T)mapper.readValue(file, clazz);
```

and put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` over the method if you are sure that this unchecked cast is accurate:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T getResult(Class clazz) { ... }
```

Actually, the cast can be done for you within the `readValue` method (if it takes `Class<T>`) so you won't need any of above.

Yes, I have checked it out:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T readValue(JsonParser p, Class<T> valueType)
    throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException
{
    DeserializationContext ctxt = createDeserializationContext(p);
    return (T) _readValue(ctxt, p, _typeFactory.constructType(valueType));
}
```

It all will be done for you. You only have to pass a correct `Class<T>` instance (not the raw type `Class`)

Comment: Right. Beside that, it might be useful to declare `clazz` as `Class<T>` in order to actually be sure that this unchecked cast is accurate, if I see it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot assign an Object type to type T variable. You will have to cast it explicitly to type T. You should use the following :

```
result = (T) mapper.readValue(file, clazz);
```

Comment: Your answer came more than 20 minutes later than Andrew's and doesn't add anything new.